# Boolean condition test - Which is good?

Tags: optimization

This question for good code and code optimization development.

```
boolean a = false;
```

which condition is best

```
if(a == false)
```

or

```
if(!a)
```

please give some description what happen with both condition in system level.

Comment: What programming language is this? What compiler are you using? What is the target platform?

Comment: @Thilo : i am asking in general term, not any selected platform or programming languages. this just example.

Comment: What's wrong with `if ((a == false) == true)` ?? ;->

Comment: "general term" in combination with "system level" and "optimization" makes this "not a real question"

Comment: @Roddy You shouldn't mix the styles. `if (((a == false) == false) == false)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!a)
```

The other is a horrible "boolean laundering" style.

Internally the meaning is the same (even in C both conditions are true exactly when `a` is `0`), so there will be no differences with respect to optimization.

Comment: Can you explain the term "boolean laundering"? I like it (reminiscent of money laundering), but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The phrase came to my mind when I simplified several instances of `if (condition) { var = true; } else { var = false; }` recently. Somehow many people don't see booleans and conditions as the same thing and need an `if` or a relation operator for conversion.  Yes, the similarity to money laundering is intended.

Answer (score 3):

These most probably end up as exactly the same instructions decided by the compiler (what ever language in question).

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same. The compiler compiles the code to whichever way is the best.

Comment: i think some difference @ system level

Comment: @AnkurPatel. In 'general terms', there is no difference in function or performance. Some specific (and very broken) compiler or interpreter might prefer one over the other, but you'd have to inspect asm code/benchmark to see...

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the history of operations done with the boolean variable.

If you have previously assigned values to a boolean variable in unusual ways like assigning it values using unlike types, using mathematical expressions, then i think 2nd choice : **if(!a)** is safer and is more likely to function as you expect but if you have always assigned values to it using only boolean variables or expressions evaluating to boolean values only, then it doesn't matter much. However, i personally find the first choice : **if(a == false)** more readable.

Regarding performance, i agree all other answers.